# Is Spring Vault compatible with both HashiCorp Vault and HashiCorp Vault Secrets?

Tags: hashicorp-vault, spring-vault

As I understand it, HashiCorp Vault and [HashiCorp Vault Secrets](https://developer.hashicorp.com/hcp/docs/vault-secrets) are two different products.

Does Spring Vault work with both? I have my secret in HashiCorp Vault Secrets and I can't figure out how to configure Spring Vault to read it.

The documentation for HashiCorp Vault Secrets provides two ways of accessing the secrets, using the [vlt CLI tool](https://developer.hashicorp.com/hcp/docs/vault-secrets/commands) or the [API](https://developer.hashicorp.com/hcp/api-docs/vault-secrets), however I am pretty new to Spring and I can't figure out how to read the secret in my application.

I've looked at the documentation for both Spring Vault and HashiCorp Vault Secrets, but the configuration for Spring Vault does not seem to line up with the way that you access a secret in HashiCorp Vault Secrets. I don't know what values to use for `vault.uri` or `vault.token`.